How to convert tensor flow lite plugin in non imperative syntax for flutter
As imperative declaration is deprecated, I try to convert my plugins without success (semicolon isn't supported):
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0" // OK
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false // OK
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false //OK
    id "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite" version "0.1.100" apply false // KO
    id "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops" version "0.1.100" apply false // KO

}

I also tried this without success:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0" // OK
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false // OK
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false // OK
    id "org.tensorflow.tensorflow.lite" version "0.1.100" apply false // KO
    id "org.tensorflow.tensorflow.lite.select.tf.ops" version "0.1.100" apply false // KO

}


I don't know which package that you are using for the tflite. But I think you don't need to change the other plugin declaration method (other than the first 3 in your code).

Deprecation of imperative plugins declaration influences only plugins. Those tensorflow artefacts belongs to dependencies block in your build.gradle, since they are runtime dependencies of your app, and not build-time dependencies of your build.
So, you plugins block should remain like this:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

And tensorflow dependencies in dependencies block:
dependencies {
    // using latest version from maven-central
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.16.1'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.16.1'

}

